# Heatmap using lists of different size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to compare two list of different size using JaroWinkler similarity. `List_1` has `5` elements and it comes from a column dataframe, e.g.

```
List_1=df['Movements'].tolist()
```

i.e. `List_1=['surrealism', 'futurism', 'impressionism', 'realism', 'neorealism']`

while `list_2` has `7` elements:

```
list_2=['romantisme', 'surrealisme', 'realisme','creativité', 'liberté', 'poete','cubism','metaphysique']
```

To calculate the JaroWinkler distance, I am using the following function:

```
jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()
```

that I apply to the column `df.Movements` as follows:

```
for m in all_mov:
     df[m] = df.Movements.apply(lambda x: jarowinkler.similarity(x, m))
    np.where(df[m] > 0.1, df[m], np.nan)
```

I would like to plot using `seaborn` heat map  only the results where `jarowinkler.similarity` is greater than `0.1`.

```
mask = np.zeros_like(df.Movements)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
with sns.axes_style("white"):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    ax = sns.heatmap(df['Movements'], mask=mask, square=False)
```

However, I can see only results for a square (i.e. only for the first 5 elements from `list_2`. 
Am I doing something wrong (e.g. considering a heat map not squared)? Is there any other way to visualise similarity between lists of different size?
Advices will be very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
for m in all_mov:
    #compute similarity
    df[m] = df.Movements.apply(lambda x: jarowinkler.similarity(x, m))

    # filter out low similarity scores
    df[m] = np.where(df[m] > 0.1, df[m], np.nan)

sns.heatmap(data=df.set_index('Movements')[all_mov])
```

which gives you something like this:

[image]